# Filling DataTable column by column C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to fill a DataTable with values from dynamically created controls. The idea is to have three columns in the DataTable, and fill them one after the other. First fill column 1, then 2, then 3. However, I am struggling to do this effectively.

What is happening is that the DataTable is being filled, but the Data in columns 1, 2 and 3 is not side by side, but instead being filled in different rows. I know this is because I am adding a row with each loop, but I have tried some other things that did not work. Could you help me out?

```
            DataTable tvpIngredients = new DataTable();
            tvpIngredients.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
            tvpIngredients.Columns.Add("Measure", typeof(string));
            tvpIngredients.Columns.Add("Ingredient", typeof(string));


                foreach (Control ctrlQtt in quantity.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrlQtt is TextBox)
                    {
                        DataRow drNew = tvpIngredients.NewRow();

                        TextBox quantity = (TextBox)ctrlQtt;
                        drNew["Quantity"] = quantity.Text;
                        tvpIngredients.Rows.Add(drNew);
                    }
                }
                foreach (Control ctrlMsr in measure.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrlMsr is DropDownList)
                    {
                        DataRow drNew = tvpIngredients.NewRow();

                        DropDownList measure = (DropDownList)ctrlMsr;
                        drNew["Measure"] = measure.SelectedValue.ToString();
                        tvpIngredients.Rows.Add(drNew);
                    }
                }

                foreach (Control ctrlIng in ingredient.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrlIng is TextBox)
                    {
                        DataRow drNew = tvpIngredients.NewRow();

                        TextBox ingredient = (TextBox)ctrlIng;
                        drNew["Ingredient"] = ingredient.Text;
                        tvpIngredients.Rows.Add(drNew);
                    }
                }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already added rows. You need to modify the row column instead.

```
            DataTable tvpIngredients = new DataTable();
            tvpIngredients.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
            tvpIngredients.Columns.Add("Measure", typeof(string));
            tvpIngredients.Columns.Add("Ingredient", typeof(string));


            foreach (Control ctrlQtt in quantity.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrlQtt is TextBox)
                {
                    DataRow drNew = tvpIngredients.NewRow();

                    TextBox quantity = (TextBox)ctrlQtt;
                    drNew["Quantity"] = quantity.Text;
                    tvpIngredients.Rows.Add(drNew);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < tvpIngredients.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ctrlMsr is DropDownList)
                {
                    DataRow drNew = tvpIngredients.NewRow();

                    DropDownList measure = (DropDownList)ctrlMsr;
                    drNew["Measure"] = measure.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    tvpIngredients.Rows[i][1].ToString() = drNew;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < tvpIngredients.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ctrlIng is TextBox)
                {
                    DataRow drNew = tvpIngredients.NewRow();

                    TextBox ingredient = (TextBox)ctrlIng;
                    drNew["Ingredient"] = ingredient.Text;
                    tvpIngredients.Rows[i][2].ToString() = drNew;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Perfect Steve! Exactly what I was looking for! Well thought! Solved it! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

To solve a problem like this you need to think about the way you model your data.
Looking at the code here I can guess that you have a Form let's call it Recipe that has at least 3 controls quantity, measure, and ingredients. These controls can contain an arbitrary number of items. It looks like they would be of equal length given that they are each related to one item in your recipe.

You could do this:

```
if(quantity.Controls.Count != measure.Controls.Count 
 || quantity.Controls.Count != ingredient.Controls.Count)
{
   throw new Exception("Invalid ingredients list");
}
var quantities = new Control[quantity.Controls.Count];
var measurements = new Control[measure.Controls.Count];
var ingredients = new Control[ingredient.Controls.Count];
quantity.Controls.CopyTo(quantities, 0);
measure.Controls.CopyTo(measurements , 0);
ingredient.Controls.CopyTo(ingredients , 0);

for(var i = 0; i < quantity.Length; ++i)
{
  // Make your new row
  // index the arrays and fill the row data in
}
```

There is probably a more elegant solution to the whole problem if you spend some time thinking through how you model it.

Comment: Thank you Naylor! I got it work with Steve's answer, but I will keep this in mind for future issues